# iOS: Get Image From HTML String

Tags: html, xcode, image, search

I have an application that is pulling articles from the web and I need to retrieve the URL for the first image in an article. Here's an example of the code for these images:

```
<img alt="Twitter (zpower)" src="http://www.example.com/image.png" width="630" height="420">
```

I need to get just the value for the src. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to parse the HTML and extract the `src` attribute. You could do it by hand, but a better way is to rely on someone else's parsing library (for instance, [ElementParser](http://touchtank.wordpress.com/element-parser/)).

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to second @ravuya's response, but also mention that you can also use the built in [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do the parsing for you.